# incompatible block pointer types objectsPassingTest:

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, nsset

I want to get filtred NSSet:

```
NSSet* contents = [self.content objectsPassingTest:^(id obj, BOOL* stop){
        NSNumber* chapterNo = ((LTContent*)obj).chapterNo;
        return [chapterNo integerValue] < 0;
    }];
```

But this code fires an error: `incompatible block pointer types sending 'int (^)(id, BOOL *)' to parameter of type 'BOOL (^)(id, BOOL *)`

If I change code:

```
NSSet* contents = [self.content objectsPassingTest:^(id obj, BOOL* stop){
        NSNumber* chapterNo = ((LTContent*)obj).chapterNo;
        BOOL a = [chapterNo integerValue] < 0;
        return a;
    }];
```

it works perfect. But I don't want to use odd line. What's wrong in first snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the explicit return type `BOOL` for the block:

```
NSSet* contents = [set objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, BOOL* stop) {
    // ...
    return [chapterNo integerValue] < 0;
}];
```

Otherwise the compiler derives the return type  from the 
return statement, and that is `int` in your case.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot block's return type:

```
NSSet* contents = [self.content objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, BOOL* stop) {
```